# Selecting part of html after scraping

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I have scraped a json file with a single `html` keyvalue containing this:

`"<div class='car_model_estimation_result__container'>\n<div class='car_model_estimation_result cobalt-mb-tight'>\n<div class='car_model_estimation_result__item'>\n<span class=\"car_model_estimation_result_amount\">720€</span>\n<p class='cobalt-text-sectionHeader'>\n<span>maximum estimés par mois</span>\n<span class='cobalt-mb-unit cobalt-Icon cobalt-Icon--size16 cobalt-Icon--colorGraphiteLight'>\n<a class=\"js_popup_trigger\" href=\"#estimate_about_with_open\"><svg viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n  <path d=\"M11 9h2V7h-2v2zm1 11c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zm0-18C6.477 2 2 6.477 2 12A10 10 0 1 0 12 2zm-1 15h2v-6h-2v6z\" />\n</svg>\n\n</a></span>\n</p>\n\n</div>\n<div class='owner_homepage_hero_estimation_cta__container'>\n<a class=\"owner_homepage_hero_estimation_cta--fullWidth cobalt-Button cobalt-Button--primary cobalt-Button--large js_rent_my_car js_rent_my_car_top js_estimation_result\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-tracking-params=\"{&quot;model_id&quot;:&quot;1519&quot;,&quot;brand_id&quot;:&quot;67&quot;,&quot;mileage&quot;:4,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;Anvers&quot;,&quot;release_year&quot;:2016,&quot;open_eligible&quot;:true,&quot;currency&quot;:&quot;EUR&quot;,&quot;earnings&quot;:720,&quot;earnings_period&quot;:&quot;month&quot;}\" data-click-location=\"top\" data-estimated-earnings=\"{&quot;model_id&quot;:&quot;1519&quot;,&quot;release_year&quot;:2016,&quot;mileage&quot;:4,&quot;within_eligible_area&quot;:true,&quot;open_eligible&quot;:true}\" href=\"/choose_open_or_standard?mileage=4&amp;model_id=1519&amp;open_eligible=true&amp;release_year=2016&amp;within_eligible_area=true\">Inscrire ma voiture</a>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n"`

I would like to get the text of the `span` attribute with class `car_model_estimation_result_amount`. Is there any way to do this without using regular expression ?

Comment: Yes, using html parsers like [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You should NEVER use a regex to extract some html attributes / tags. Use regex only to extract informations inside unstructured text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the text into a [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) [Selector](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#parsel.selector.Selector) and use it as you would use `response` to find the desired data:

```
from parsel import Selector
selector = Selector(json_value['html'])
desired_text = selector.css('span.car_model_estimation_result_amount').get()
```